# ksqlDB for finding average last hour, and store results back to a kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb, redpanda

We have a readpanda (kafka compatible) source, with sensor data. Can we do the following:

1. Every hour, find the average sensor data last hour for each sensor
2. Store them back to a topic

Comment: Sure, ksql can do (tumbling, one hour) windowed averages. What have you tried?

Comment: But won't doing this create a continuous updated table/topic? I just want one single value for the average between two timestamps, for each sensor.

Comment: It will, yes. If you create a table, though, you can query it externally, given a key, such as the starting hour. But also, you said you did want the results back into a topic, so what's wrong with a continuous stream?

Comment: It would make consuming these "average" messages a bit simpler. It would also fit well with our architecture for internal message queues. Materialize has this feature. But thanks, will think it through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create a materialized view over the stream of events that can be queried by other applications. Your source publishes the individual events to Kafka/Redpanda, another process observers the events and makes them available as queryable "tables" for other applications. Elaborating a few options:

KSQLdb is likely a default choice as it comes as "native" in the Kafka/Confluent stack. Be careful with using it over your production Kafka cluster. It has heavy impact on the cluster performance. See the [basic tutorial](https://redpanda.com/blog/ksqldb-materialized-cache) or the [advanced tutorial](https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/0.26.0-ksqldb/tutorials/materialized/#query-the-materialized-views).

Use an out-of-the box solution for materialized views such as Materialize. It's easiest to setup/use and doesn't stress the Kafka broker. However, it is single-node only as of now (06/2022). See [the tutorial](https://redpanda.com/blog/loT-streaming-data-materialize-redpanda).

Another popular option is using a stream processor and store hourly aggregates to an attached database (for example Flink storing data to Redis). This is a do-it-yourself approach. Have a look on [Hazelcast](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-demos/tree/master/realtime-trade-monitor). It is one process running both stream processing services and a queryable store.